# Convert days and years to day month and year format in php

Tags: php, date, date-conversion

So I have the number of days and the year in the following format:

```
322 days
2009 year
```

I need to convert this to `2009-11-18`

Is there a function in php to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use `mktime` and `date`:

```
$days = 322;
$year = 2009;
echo date('Y-m-d', mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, $days, $year));
```

**[Output:](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JSVWem)** 2009-11-18

Comment: Are you sure about the 1 for the month ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$newformat = new DateTime::createFromFormat('Y z', "2009 322")->format('Y-M-d');
```

Relevant docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat is a static method, you can't use `new`. Also, your format string should be `'Y-m-d'`. And, it produces a date that is [1 day off](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6HMOvb).

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

The hard way ( and as a bonus, I parse the input example you gave :p ):

```
list($day, $foo, $year, $bar) = sscanf("322 days 2009 year", "%d %s %d %s");
$timestamp = mktime (0,0,0, 1, $day, $year);
echo date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

We do have [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) in php, which can easily pull timestamp from year:

```
echo $time = strtotime( '1.1.2009');
// 1230764400
```

And chain it with adding days:

```
echo $newTime = strtotime( '+322 days', $time);
// 1258585200
echo date( 'r', $newTime);
// Thu, 19 Nov 2009 00:00:00 +0100
echo date( 'Y-m-d', $newTime);
// 2009-11-19
// output will be 19 instead of 18 (due to how strtotime handles + days), you
// should use +321 days instead than
```

<sub>btw: I like Marc B's answer better .)</sub>

Comment: `2009-11-19` is one day off, the desired output was `2009-11-18` - Is this intentional?

Comment: @nickb I didn't realize that. Thank you, added note to comment.